# onClick only triggered with double tap

Tags: android, onclick, onclicklistener

I am having issues with my `onClick` event being triggered. I have a `ListView` in a fragment and the `onClick` listener is fired only when I double tap the view. It seems like there might be something stupid that I have in the configuration, but nothing in my code base is jumping out at me. Has anyone seen this issue before? Is there some setting, or some issue with `ListView`'s that I missed in the docs? My xml has `autolink='all'` on but besides that it is vanilla.

When I changed my listener to `onTouch` it worked with one click, and I am lost at ideas on how to fix this.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Are you setting onItemClickListener or onClickListener? The first is what you should be using.

Comment: @Shadesblade When I populate the `ListView` with `TextView`'s I am creating `onClickListener`s. I tried `onItemClickListener`, but it wasn't working properly. I will give it another shot, thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: OnClickListener() is fired when you tap on the View (not elements in it) and cannot be used to accurately get elements in a ListView. Your other option is to have a Custom Adapter extend `BaseAdapter` and have your onClickListener on the `View` passed in the `getView()` method. Still onItemClickListener() is what you want. BTW you set the onItemClickListener() on the listview itself. For instance `ListView listView = new ListView(); listView.setOnItemClickListener()`

Comment: @Shadesblade thanks for the info, that seems to be the issue that I was running into. I must have missed it somewhere in the docs saying that about `ListView`s. If this was an answer I would accept it.